# Insert a Featured Video

Tags: jquery, html, embed

I'm trying to put a video as featured in my theme, i mean, to be shown by the tag "the_post_thumbnail ('')", without using any plugin. Is this possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible as-written in core. `the_post_thumbnail()` uses the ID of the attachment post-type that has been selected as the *featured image* for the post, then outputs the image associated with that attachment post-type.

You would have to filter `the_post_thumbnail()` in some manner, but your question specified "without a Plugin".